# PHP how to return timezone from country code and region

Tags: php, geolocation, timezone, geoip

I have the Country code and Region code -> how to convert those 2 data into timezone name ?

Example

```
<?php
echo geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region('CA', 'QC');
//returns America/Montreal
?>
```

I tried to install

```
geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region
```

but it seem outdated (older version of maxmind...)

Is there for 2019/2020 a similar solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Follow the instructions in the first comment of this page:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install PECL extension GeoIP.

Please refer https://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php.

** only until PHP 7.1 (7.2 and more will not work with this PECL extension)

Comment: Please do not use the link in the answer instead try to explain here because in case of link broke it will be very difficult to find answers.

Comment: It is not compatible with any PHP versions later than 7.1 (I use 7.3)